# Typescript - property does not exist on type '{..}'

Tags: angular, typescript, object, properties

I have a method which returns the following object: 
[image]

Later on, when I wish to get a property of this object, e.g. name I get the following issue: [image]

What am I doing wrong here and how can I avoid this?

Comment: post your code pleas not screen shots.

Comment: Post your code where you initialized `conversationMetaData` and avoid posting screenshots for code lines.

Comment: I've tried to print `this.createObject` and what it shows on console is just the code as you've write it. Are you trying to have a function that return an object initialized on the parameter you gave to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array of objects. either you need a object or you will have to find the index within that array. like `conversationMetaData[index].name`

Answer (score 0):

**conversationMetaData** is an array. So it's obvious it doesn't have **name** attribute.
You have to access the corresponding element in the array like below.

```
conversationMetaData[id].name;
```